# Calling C function with OpenMP from Python causes segmentation fault at the end

Tags: python, c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, openmp

I have written a Python script that calls a C-function which is parallelized using OpenMP (variables from Python to C-function were passed using ctypes-wrapper). The C-function works correctly producing the desired output. But I get a segmentation fault at the end of the Python code. I suspect it has something to do with threads spawned by OpenMP since the seg-fault does not occur when OpenMP is disabled.

On the Python side of the code (which calls the external C-function) I have:

```
...
C_Func = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary ('./Cinterface.so')

C_Func.Receive_Parameters.argtypes = (...list of ctypes variable-type ...)
C_Func.Receive_Parameters.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

C_Func.Perform_Calculation.argtypes = ( )
C_Func.Perform_Calculation.restypes = ctypes.c_void_p
```

and on the C-side, generic form of the function is:

```
void Receive_Parameters (....list of c variable-type ...)
{
  ---Take all data and parameters coming from python---
  return;
}

void Perform_Calculation ( )
{

#pragma omp parallel default(shared) num_threads(8) private (....)
{
  #pragma omp for schedule (static, 1) reduction (+:p)
    p+= core_calculation (...list of variables....)
}
  return;
}


float core_calculation (...list of variables...)
{
  ----all calculations done here-----
}
```

I have following questions and associated confusion:

1. Does Python have any control in the operation of threads spawned by the OpenMP inside the C-function? The reason I ask this is that the C-function receives pointers to arrays allocated in the heap by Python. Can OpenMP threads perform operations on this array in parallel without bothering about where it was allocated?
2. Do I need to do anything in the Python code before calling the C-function, say release the GIL to allow OpenMP threads to be spawned in C-function? If yes, how does one do that?
3. Do I have to release the GIL in the C-function (before OpenMP parallel block)?

Comment: Forgot to add, the C-function takes pointers to the array allocated in python. Just wondering if that could be one of the reason for seg-fault.

Comment: You forgot to add a [mcve] (read that page very carefully). It's useless to speculate about your error without a specific code to reproduce it.

Comment: Sorry, the code is too long to be posted here. I have put together some doubts which I think could be reason for the seg fault I see.

Answer (score -1):

I have SWIG (http://swig.org), a C and C++ wrapper generator for Python and other languages organizing the GIL release for me. The generated code does not look trivial and is using the new releasing/acquiring techniques from [PEP311](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0311/). However, the old technique explained in the PEP might be sufficient for you. I hope some more competent person will answer later, but this answer is better than nothing, I guess. But errors in an OpenMP loop are not handled gracefully, have you checked the C function with OpenMP outside of Python?

Comment: Yes, the C function with OpenMP works fine outside Python.